# Spring Cloud streams kinesis binder consumer groups - kcl vs dynomodbstore

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

What is the suggested solution to use consumer group management.
As far as I understood there are two ways

1) Use the DynamoDbMetadataStore and DynamoDbLockRegistry

2) Use the kpl kcl features provided by AWS? See https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/13/spring-integration-aws-2-2-ga-and-spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder-1-2-ga-available
By default kpl kcl is disabled.

What are the pros cons regarding the two solutions?

Answer (score 1):

@Weso

With my short experience on Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis binder.

`Approach 1.`

If your Kinesis stream dynamically updating shards / creating additional consumer on autoscale. - rebalancing is not happening.
There were events where All the shards were locked by single consumer.

`Approach 2:`

KPLKCL is using KCL 1.x from AWS.

It works well with dynamic scaling and rebalancing.

Note: You might see the problem with dynamodb auto table Creation with current release 2.0.2 ( I am using 2.1.0 - currently)